# Parse multiple values in a php string

Tags: javascript, php, regex, parsing

I am stuck at one point and newbie at regex:

I need to parse a string in php and find out multiple values starting from particular pattern.

But that string which needs to be parsed is actually a javascript code.

This is the string (javascript code) that needs to be parsed :

```
<script src="http://192.168.1.172/jsScripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
     type="text/css"  
     href="http://192.168.1.172/adqCss/adqExapandable.css">
<script src="http://192.168.1.172/jsScripts/adqExpandable.js"></script>
<script>
    var t1 = ${kom_demo_test1};
    var t2 = ${kom_demo_test2};
    var url = 'http://demo.com';
</script>
```

Now i need to identify all words that start with **${kom_dom_** and then i want to store test1 , test2 in an array .

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Will you parse that in PHP or Javascript?

Comment: I will parse it in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that quite easily using [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all), something like this:

```
<?php
$input= '<script src="http://192.168.1.172/jsScripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
     type="text/css"  
     href="http://192.168.1.172/adqCss/adqExapandable.css">
<script src="http://192.168.1.172/jsScripts/adqExpandable.js"></script>
<script>
    var t1 = ${kom_demo_test1};
    var t2 = ${kom_demo_test2};
    var url = \'http://demo.com\';
</script>';

$matches= array(); // An array to store the results
$results= preg_match_all('/\${kom_demo_(.*)}/', $input, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Which will produce:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '${kom_demo_test1}' (length=17)
      1 => string '${kom_demo_test2}' (length=17)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string 'test1' (length=5)
      1 => string 'test2' (length=5)
```

So `$matches[1]` contains the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is an expression that will work for this.  Capture group 1 will give you everything after `kom_demo_`.

`/\$\{kom_demo_([^\}]+)\}/`